# resizing images - imagemagick using - quality and jpeg:extent in one command

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick to resize images...
however I want to resize the images so that it uses both jpeg:extent and quality...

i.e. if I have a large image that i want to resize, and I use the following: 
-resize 720 -quality 80
if the resulting image is larger than 250kb then I want the command to use `jpeg:extent=250kB` instead of `-quality 80`

Is this possible to do in one command?.. or do I have to do multiple proceedures to achieve this?... regards J

By the by, I dont want to just use `jpeg:extent=250kB` as if the image saved at 80% quality is alot smaller than 250kb i am creating images larger than they need be... cheers J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both options at the same time. According to documentation:

> Restrict the maximum JPEG file size, for example -define
>   jpeg:extent=400kb.

This command doesn't define the actual size, it only defines a size limit. This means that quality will be 80 if the size limit is not reached

Comment: Thats incorrect. According to the documentation here - http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php
`The -quality option is ignored if it is also present.`

Comment: That wasn't stated back there two years ago when I answered this question
http://web.archive.org/web/20120628181412/http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php